# AWS docker container is not inheriting the host instance role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to access S3 bucket from a Camel Router running in docker container deployed in ECS.

Host EC2 instance has IAM policies which provide access to S3 bucket and I have verified this by running a standalone router directly in EC2. But when I tried the program inside a container it is throwing an exception stating that "Access Denied" to S3 bucket.

After this, I tried providing a Task IAM Role by adding TaskRoleArn in my Cloudformation but that didn't help, still the same exception.

Not sure if I am missing anything here, any suggestions?

[Edit, adding the IAM policy here]
This is my IAM policy for host, similar one I created for Task Role as well with the trust relationship to ‘ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com’

This is my IAM policy for host, similar one I created for Task Role as well with the trust relationship to ‘ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com’

```
EC2Role:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Statement:
    - Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service:
        - ec2.amazonaws.com
        - ecs.amazonaws.com
      Action:
      - sts:AssumeRole
  Path: /Developer/
  Policies:
  - PolicyName: ecs-service
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
        - logs:CreateLogStream
        - logs:CreateLogGroup 
        - logs:DescribeLogGroups
        - logs:DescribeLogStreams
        - logs:PutLogEvents
        - logs:GetLogEvents
        - logs:FilterLogEvents
        Resource: '*'
  - PolicyName: ep-bucket-policy
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
      - Sid: bucket1
        Effect: Allow
        Action:
        - s3:GetObject
        - s3:GetObjectAcl
        - s3:AbortMultipartUpload
        - s3:GetObjectTagging
        - s3:DeleteObject
        - s3:ListMultipartUploadParts
        Resource: *
      - Sid: bucket2
        Effect: Allow
        Action: s3:ListObjects
        Resource: "*"
  - PolicyName: ep-ecr-policy
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
      - Sid: ecr1
        Effect: Allow
        Action:
        - ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
        - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
        - ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy
        - ecr:DescribeRepositories
        - ecr:ListImages
        - ecr:BatchGetImage
        Resource:
        - !Sub 'arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/*’
      - Sid: ecr2
        Effect: Allow
        Action:
        - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken   
        Resource: '*'
  - PolicyName: ep-ecs-policy
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
      - Sid: ecs1
        Effect: Allow
        Action:
        - ecs:SubmitTaskStateChange
        - ecs:RegisterContainerInstance
        - ecs:SubmitContainerStateChange
        - ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance
        Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:ecs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:cluster/Custom-*’
      - Sid: ecs2
        Effect: Allow
        Action:
        - ecs:Poll
        - ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint
        - ecs:StartTelemetrySession
        - ecs:CreateCluster
        Resource: "*"
```

Comment: Do you have the trust relationship in the policy? Please post Iam role policies.

Comment: Updated the question with the policy due to the comments character limit

Comment: I don't see `‘ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com` in your template?

Comment: I have created another role, same policies but added 'ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com' in trust relationship and assigned that role to TaskRoleArn while creating my Task Definition. Do I need to add 'ecs-tasks' in host role as well?